# How to use a variable with "gather" and "select"

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to assign a text to a variable and then use that variable within my pipeline. I extensively use `gather` and `select`.

In the example below, I want to be able to use `x` within my pipeline code:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% head

mtcars %>% 
  gather(type, value, mpg:am) %>% head

mtcars %>% select(mpg:am) %>% head
```

#### This the variable I want to use

```
x <- "mpg:am"
```

#### None of what I have tried has worked

```
mtcars %>% 
  gather(type, value, get(x)) %>% head


mtcars %>% 
  gather(type, value, !!rlang::sym(x)) %>% head


mtcars %>% select(x) %>% head
mtcars %>% select(!!rlang::sym(x)) %>% head
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try to specify the two separately? ie `y <- 'mpg'`; `z <- 'am'`;
`mtcars %>% select(!! rlang::sym(y): !!rlang::sym(z))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `quote/quo` it and then evaluate with `!!`

```
x <- quo(mpg:am)
out1 <- mtcars %>%
            gather(type, value, !! x)
```

Checking the output with

```
out2 <- mtcars %>%
           gather(type, value, mpg:am)
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wondering @akrun if there is a way to do this while using `'mpg:am'` as a character string?

Comment: @Brandon Problem is that after converting to `sym`, it still is having backquotes

Comment: Ah, so that would mean it is not accomplishable then?

Comment: @Brandon I couldn't find a simple way.  May be the option that you showed in the comment is the simplest one